# Linux (Raspbian) - Running script at login(auto) and keeping window in foreground for interaction

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have tried everything to make this work. login scripts, LXDE-pi autostart, cron task @reboot, init.d, and I cannot get my script running with a terminal window running in the foreground so that I can interact with it. I can get it to run but only in background.  Is there any way I can get a script that simply runs: "python /home/pi/myscript.py" at startup and leaves the terminal window open with the script running for my keyboard inputs?  I would rather not use the /dev/input/event if at all possible.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a simple flag.. what I did was edit ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart  with

```
@lxterminal -e /home/pi/autoscript.sh
```

and in that file, I added

```
cd /home/pi/
python -i 2Trackmain.py
```

I wasn't using the -i flag, so every time I pressed Enter to move through the interactive py script, it exited the terminal, using -i will keep the window open for your interaction.  And I only had to add the  change directory part b/c the script called other scripts in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply running `python /home/pi/myscript.py` at startup will run your script without any terminal. So there is no window that can be kept open. The behavior you want can be achieved by starting an terminal application and let it execute your script.

e. g. using xterm:

```
xterm -e "python /home/pi/myscript.py"
```

or lxterminal:

```
lxterminal --command "python /home/pi/myscript.py"
```

Comment: This does work when I modify .bashrc with a script: something.sh that contains:    lxterminal -e "python /home/pi/myscript.py"    but it will only execute the script AFTER I open the terminal myself, it will open a new terminal with my python script running.  What am I missing to make it open the terminal itself and run the script?